# Let $d$ be a square free integer. Show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $d$ be a square free integer. Show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is an integral domain.

Here $1+0\sqrt{d}$ is identity of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$. Also commutative property can be shown easily. But I can't show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ has no zero divisor with $d$ is square free. Could you please help?

Comment: Which definition of this ring are you using?

Comment: Hint: Your ring is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $a,b \in \Bbb Z$, note that if $a + b\sqrt{d}$ is a zero divisor, then the same must hold for the product 
$$
(a + b\sqrt{d})(a - b \sqrt{d}) = a^2 - db^2.
$$
However, $0$ is the only zero divisor of $\Bbb Z \subset \Bbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$. So, we have $a^2 = db^2$. Because $d$ is square-free, this only occurs when $a=b=0$.